# Check docker connection for user and password

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, dockerhub

we have some wizard with automation tool,

the wizard have 3 simple step

> 1 provide docker registry user

> 2. provide registry password

> 3. provide the domain to upload the image

it could be artifactory or dockerhub.

The problem is that sometimes user provide wrong credentials and the wizard says login success(using docker api's...), which is **incorrect**. as when the user push an image after he  get an error un-autorized , my question is how should I handle it in the wizard ? maybe build the [screatch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) image and push it to see if user provided the right credentials and authorized ?

my questions:

1. is it possible to push an image without file, to provide the content via command? or to push some dummy image...
2. is there other option to verify that the user successfully logged in? we dont get appropriate message when the user doenst provide the right credintials ...

**UPDATE**
After checking it further it seems that we are not using docker we are using [img](http://github.com/genuinetools/img)  and sometimes you can provide **wrong** password and you get the **successful** login info, is there a way to call to docker api/2 with the user server and password to see that user is successful login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be calling

```
docker login -u username -p password server
```

(or any pendant from library if your wizard uses some sort of library like Docker.DotNet or similar) from your wizard and check the resultcode. If it's `0` the login is ok, otherwise it's not.

Comment: thanks, but what is `server`? can you give practical example ?

Comment: The registry you are trying to push to. You can omit it if you are pushing to docker hub. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Comment: sorry after checking it further it seems that we are not using docker we are using `img` https://github.com/genuinetools/img and sometimes you can provide wrong password and you get the successfull login info, is there a way to call to docker `api/2` with the user server and password to see that user is successful login?

Comment: Sorry, don't know/use that tool so i can't help you there. Just discovering the basics of docker myself ...